# DataFrame write to CSV not supporting some characters

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I am trying to parse the XML file and write to DataFrame result to CSV file.

My problem is some of characters are not supported when i write the output to the CSV. For eg, there is a field **`Nectarine tree named &#x2018;Polar Zee&#x2019;`** its writes like **`Nectarine tree named â€˜Polar Zeeâ€™`**.

Is there any settings need to be change? or any properties need to be added?

Comment: How are you reading the XML?

Comment: by using databrics library

Comment: Two more question: 1) which version? 2) if you try to print the string before you output the CSV, how does it appear?